# Vim remembering settings of edited files

Tags: vim

I read some where about creating files in vim to save things like open windows and folds. I tried to Google it but had trouble finding reference to it. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Regarding your plugin question - please create a new question for this and move the 2nd paragraph to it. Multiple questions as one post are discouraged on SE.

Comment: fair enough I coupled them since they where the same thought in my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for vim Session files which are an extension of viminfo ones:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#Session

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#viminfo